# TF2 Mann vs Machine POP files - what can you do with a Tank?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-mann-vs-machine

When designing wave patterns for MvM, you can create a tank thus:

```
Tank
{
    Health  1000
    Name    Tank
    Speed   75
    StartingPathTrackNode   boss_path_1
    OnKilledOutput
    {
        Target  boss_dead_relay
        Action  Trigger
    }
    OnBombDroppedOutput
    {
        Target  boss_deploy_relay
        Action  Trigger
    }
}
```

The style implies that there could be other *Output directives, but I cannot find any other examples. The info in https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Tank_boss suggests other outputs, but there's no "OnBombDropped" there, and "OnHealthBelow90PercentOutput" is an unrecognized directive in the pop file.

Ideally, I would like to be able to either set an attribute on the tank, which could be viewed in a SourcePawn plugin (triggering on the entity being created), or have a parameterized event, perhaps firing User1, which I could then hook.

I suspect there's no way to do this with just SourceMod.